# STM32F0 - Multiple interrupts from one Timer?

Tags: timer, stm32, delay

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way of using any of the timers to generate interrupts at more than one delay time.

E.G. I want to be able to start a timer, then have it cause interrupts at say 20us, 50us, 100us, 300us.
I can see that its perfectly possibly (and easy) to have timers cause an interrupt when the end of the count has elapsed (using HAL) but having trouble working out if I can do what I want using only one timer.
I notice some timers are 4 channel but not sure if they can be set as required.

I guess my fall back is to use one timer for each (but ideally I would like to keep other timers in case they are needed for other tasks).

I've read the docs but having trouble understanding if the device can be configured as I want it to.

Comment: Another option (in addition to the perfectly good one by @Flexz) is to use DMA to automatically reconfigure the timer as appropriate. See section 5 of AN4776. Maybe harder to set up initially, but it's "fire and forget" once it is working and doesn't require your ISR to do anything special.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way - is to change the timer period (write a different value to the `ARR` register, use `__HAL_TIM_SET_AUTORELOAD` macro if you prefer HAL) in each interrupt. This way every other period could be different.

Just keep in mind `ARR` buffering, or *Auto-reload preload*, see `ARPE` bit decription in `TIMx_CR1`. if it is enabled - the new value of ARR will be taken in account only after the next update event.

Comment: You can force the force reload by setting the `UG` bit in `TIMx_EGR` register

Comment: @0___________ Setting the `UG` bit also clears the counter and prescaler counter, increasing the effective timer period. This could be an unwanted side effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can have more than one interrupt generated during one cycle. You need to use output compare registers and enable their interrupts.

In the timer interrupt handler routine you will need to check what has triggered the interrupt.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can achieve it. One a little blunt and simple, another one slightly more complicated, but once set up, very effective and quick to process.

Approach number 1, a little limited, but also a little simpler: use capture/compare (in this case, compare specifically) to trigger an interrupt. Since timers have up to 4 capture/compare values, you can have up to 4 interrupts. You will have to check which exactly interrupt fired tho in the handler. Which specifically compare value, I mean.

Approach number 2, more flexible, more precise, but a bit more hassle to set up: master-slave timers. You can have one timer (including basic) be the clock source for the other timers ("tick" on the rising edge of master slave setting). For example, master timer ticks at 10kHz, and its slave timer uses its output as a clock source and ticks to, say, 50. Or 100. You can have multiple slaves. Depending on what timer's interrupt fires, you know right away how much time exactly passed, no need to check values in compare register or anything.

Mixed method: slave timers can have capture/compare too by the way, if you're into that. You can create huge timer chains if you want to.

You have a dozen timers in your MCU, you can probably spare 1 or 2 more for this purpose. Once you get it working, should make your life very easy.

This is how I set up a timer that is a slave, but also a master to another timer. TMR is TIM3 with TIM1 as a master:

```
/*
 * CR1 reset value = 0x00000000
 * ARR is not buffered
 * upcounter (default)
 * update request source: only overflow/underflow
 *
 * */
TMR->CR1 = 0x00; //reset
TMR->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_URS;

/*
 * 108MHz Clock, 64000 prescaler -> 2kHz Timer Clock
 * Reload value 6, Period = 6/2000s = 3ms
 * */
TMR->PSC = (108000U / 2U) - 1U; //APB1 is 54MHz, timer is 2x APB1 Freq, so now the timer is at 2kHz; 16-bit value!!! 65535 max!
TMR->ARR = 6U - 1U; //6 ticks at 2kHz is 3ms
TMR->CNT = 0x00; //start value
TMR->EGR |= TIM_EGR_UG; //force update event and load all values into registers
TMR->SR &= ~TIM_SR_UIF; //force clear update event

/*
 * SMCR Slave Mode Control Register reset value = 0x00000000
 * Trigger Selection - ITR0 (TIM1 as Master for TIM3)
 * Slave Mode Selection - Trigger Mode - The counter starts at a rising edge of the trigger TRGI (but it is not
 *  reset). Only the start of the counter is controlled (0b0110)
 */
TMR->SMCR = 0x00; //reset
TMR->SMCR |= (0x00 << TIM_SMCR_TS_Pos) | (0x00 << 16U) | (0x06 << TIM_SMCR_SMS_Pos);

/*
 * CR2 reset value = 0x00000000
 * Master Mode Selection 1: OC1REF Triggers TRGO to start another timer
 * Master Mode Selection 2: reset
 * Compare value: 4 (output LOW: CNT = 0, 1, 2, 3; output HIGH CNT = 4, 5)
 * Duty cycle: 33.33%
 * Output compare 1 mode - PWM mode 2 (0b0111)
 *
 * */
TMR->CR2 = 0x00; //reset
TMR->CR2 |= (0x04 << TIM_CR2_MMS_Pos); //OC1REF as TRGO
TMR->CCR1 = 4U;
TMR->CCMR1 = 0x00;
TMR->CCMR1 |= (0x07 << TIM_CCMR1_OC1M_Pos);

/*
 * Capture Compare Enable Register
 * Polarity: default - active high
 * Capture Compare Output Enable
 * */
TMR->CCER = 0x00; //reset
TMR->CCER |= TIM_CCER_CC1E;
```

The rest of my example/training project, including screenshots of waveform, are here: [Github Chained Timers Demo](https://github.com/ellectroid/STM32F746-CMSIS-Chained-Timers-Demo). There you will find TIM1 to be the master, TIM3 its slave and the master of TIM5, and so on. Timers are connected in different master-slave modes.